# MySQL offset date in group by

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which is pulling data fine. It currently groups data by month and then year. I am trying to group the monthly data from the 19th of one month to the 18th of the next so that it fits in with our financial months as opposed to calander months. Is this possible?

```
SELECT
    sum(invoice.invoice_amount_payable)AS invoice_totals,
    company.company_label AS company_label,
    MONTHNAME(invoice.invoice_date_paid)AS MONTH,
    YEAR(invoice.invoice_date_paid)AS YEAR
FROM
    invoice
INNER JOIN company ON invoice.company_id = company.company_id
WHERE
    invoice.invoice_active = 1
AND invoice.invoice_status_id = 7
AND invoice.invoice_date_deleted = 0
AND invoice.invoice_date_paid >= '2009-1-1'
AND invoice.invoice_date_paid <= '2011-8-20'
GROUP BY
    MONTH(invoice.invoice_date_paid),
    YEAR(invoice.invoice_date_paid)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(invoice.invoice_date_paid),
    MONTH(invoice.invoice_date_paid)
```

Comment: You can do arbitrary calculations in a group-by parameter, so `GROUP BY IF(....date offset calculation ..., 1, 0)` would work.

Comment: @Marc B - would you be able to explain this a little further, would I be able to group all my months in this way. So I would end up with say 24 different groups for a two year period? Thanks.

Comment: Create a UDF that calculates fiscal year/month. You could then do a simple `GROUP BY fiscal(invoice_date_paid)` and you'd automatically have your proper year/month grouping based on your fiscal year. Details on UDF here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-function-udf.html. You could do the fiscal calculation directly in the query, but most likely you'd want to re-use it elsewhere, so a UDF is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

To use the month and year functions of mysql you could simply shift your invoice day by the required offset like:

```
invoice_date_paid + INTERVAL 19 DAY
```

Comment: Surely this wouldn't group them correctly? It would simply add 19 days to each date. So one which falls in on say the 14th February I want to be grouped in the January month which should run from 19th Jan - 20th Feb. Wouldn't this interval simply add add 19 days, moving it into the March category?

Comment: The `+ 19` was just to give you the idea. In your case you should subtract, e.g. Jan19-Feb18 minus 18 days = Jan1-Jan31. Use this in your `GROUP BY` clause. I don't know if you want to shift your actual payment date in your result so you probably won't use it in the `SELECT ...`.